# Html progess bar with text color change

Tags: html, css

I have problem with my progress bar. At this moment I have code like this:

```css
.progress-bar-green2 {
  background: #70af28;
}

.progress-bar,
.progress {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.progress-bar .bar,
.progress .bar {
  position: initial;
  top: 0;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  /*position: absolute;*/
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
}

.progress-bar .bar span,
.progress .bar span {
  /*display: block;*/
  /*width: 400px;*/
  height: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  z-index: 50;
}

.progress-bar .bar.positive,
.progress .bar.positive {
  background: #70af28;
  left: 0;
  width: 54%;
  -webkit-animation: animate-positive 4s;
  animation: animate-positive 4s;
}

.progress-bar .bar.positive span,
.progress .bar.positive span {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  color: #fff;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  z-index: 99;
}

.progress-bar .bar.negative,
.progress .bar.negative {
  background: none;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  /*width: 46%;*/
  -webkit-animation: animate-negative 4s;
  animation: animate-negative 4s;
  position: absolute;
  /*width: 100%;*/
  z-index: 5;
  color: #70af28;
  text-align: center;
}

.progress-bar .bar.negative span,
.progress .bar.negative span {
  /*right: 0;*/
  color: #70af28;
  left: unset;
  right: unset;
  position: unset;
  z-index: 100;
}

@-webkit-keyframes animate-positive {
  0% {
    width: 0%;
  }
}

@keyframes animate-positive {
  0% {
    width: 0%;
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes animate-negative {
  0% {
    width: 100%;
  }
}

@keyframes animate-negative {
  0% {
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.5/umd/popper.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.5/umd/popper-utils.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


<div class="progress rl-progress border-section">
  <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-green progress-bar-green2" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="40" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100"></div>
  <div class="bar positive">
    <span>0:30 </span>
  </div>
  <div class="bar negative">
    <span>0:30</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

My problem is that the `z-index` in text overlaps, unfortunately the progress bar must have a width of 100%. Are there any methods to solve this problem? The final effect is very simple, I would like that, when the progress progresses to the text, the text changed to white.

Comment: Your code snippet is throwing a script error.

Comment: Why are you importing popper-utils? It's not needed